# Input string was not in a correct format for TextBox c# application

Tags: c#

I have 6 Text boxes and i want to append the textboxes entered text to a csv file 
but it **throws error** : Input string was not in a correct format.

**below is the code can any one rewrite the working code**

```
String filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName,"fetching.csv");
String strSeperator=",";
StringBuilder sbOutput = new StringBuilder();

int env = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); //error is throwing from this line
int user = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);//error is throwing from this line
int pass = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);//error is throwing from this line
int host = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);//error is throwing from this line
int port = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);//error is throwing from this line
int service = Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text);//error is throwing from this line     

int[][] inaOutput = new int[][]{new int[]{env,user,pass,host,port,service}};
int ilength = inaOutput.GetLength(0);
for(int i=0;i<ilength;i++)
sbOutput.AppendLine(String.Join(strSeperator,inaOutput[i]));

File.AppendAllText(filePath,sbOutput.ToString());
```

Comment: Where is the error thrown?

Comment: i have edited the code please look at it where the error is throwing

Comment: Are you sure that, for example,  `user` and `host` can be integers? Those looks like strings. But, since you're writing to a file, they're all string in the end. Don't use this: `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` to get the path to you executable. Use `Application.StartupPath`.

Answer (score 1):

Use tryparse to check if the value of the textbox is valid integer.

try this.

```
int env = 0 ,user = 0,pass = 0,host = 0,port = 0,service = 0;

if(!Int32.TryParse(txt1.Text, out env) || 
   !Int32.TryParse(txt2.Text, out user) ||
   !Int32.TryParse(txt3.Text, out pass) ||
   !Int32.TryParse(txt4.Text, out host) ||
   !Int32.TryParse(txt5.Text, out port) ||
   !Int32.TryParse(txt6.Text, out service))
{
   //Not all is valid
}
```

Comment: You can do: `Int32.TryParse(txt1.Text, out int env)` instead. No need to declare all the variables in advance.

Comment: with my current version of vs, declaring inside a tryparse is not possible. if it can work on more updated vstudio. its much good looking than my initial Answer so you can use that  :)

Answer (score 0):

That code is expecting all of your text boxes to contain valid integers.  If any of them are blank or contain characters other than 0-9, it'll throw that exception.  Some of those fields sounds like you expect text input, instead of integer inputs. If you want plain text instead of integers, use `string` instead of `int` and don't `Convert.ToInt32()`

```
string env = textBox1.Text;
string user = textBox2.Text;
string pass = textBox3.Text;
string host = textBox4.Text;
string port = textBox5.Text;
string service = textBox6.Text;

string[][] inaOutput = new string[][]{new string[]{env,user,pass,host,port,service}};
...
```

Comment: thank you TIm it helped me ... but one problem here output is been shown on same line it should append to new line :

Comment: dev,hr,hr,localhost,1521,orcl.192.167.0.1uat,uat,uat,uat,uat,uat the uat uat uat ... should display on new line